# Adding class to selectpicker dropdown on Submit

Tags: jquery, validation, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm trying to make the dropdown here have the added/removed class (`input-validation-error`) added to `<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select required"` when "Continue" is clicked, vs only when the dropdown selection is changed.

The `input-validation-error` class would have a red border on "Continue" click, to show the user that they need to select from the dropdown. I'm using [selectpicker](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) to restyle the Bootstrap dropdowns, and [jquery validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) for the validation.

```
.input-validation-error button {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

<select name="country" id="country" class="required selectpicker">
      <option value="">Select Country</option>
      <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
      [...]
</select>


$(function () {
  $('select[name^="country"]').change(function () {
    var selValue = $(this).val();
    $("#form-jsvalidate").validate().element(this);
    if (selValue.length > 0) {
      $(this).next('div').removeClass("input-validation-error");
    }
    else {
      $(this).next('div').addClass("input-validation-error");
    }
  });
});
```

I believe it should be something like `$('.btn-submit-val').on('click', function() { var selValue = $('select[name^="country"]').val();` but obviously not since that and everything else I've tried isn't working. Any point in the right direction is much appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/25795/

Edit: Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand where exactly you want to put the error message but I did a few edits in your fiddle, check now if it helps.

Please be more clear in where you want to put your error message.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form-jsvalidate").validate({
        errorClass:'input-validation-error',
                          validClass:'success',
                          errorElement:'button',
                          highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) { 
                            $(element).parents("div.control-group").addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass); 

                          },
        rules: {
            "country": {
                required: true
            },
        },
        messages: {
            "country": {
                required: "Country is required"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            alert('valid');
            return false;
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form-jsvalidate').validate().settings.ignore = ':not(select.selectpicker, select:visible, input:visible, textarea:visible)';
});

$('.btn-submit-val').on('click', function() {
    $("#form-jsvalidate").valid();
    return false;
});

$(function () {
        $('select[name^="country"]').change(function () {
            var selValue = $(this).val();
            $("#form-jsvalidate").validate().element(this);
            if (selValue.length > 0) {
                $(this).next('div').removeClass("input-validation-error");
            }
            else {
                $(this).next('div').addClass("input-validation-error");
            }
        });
        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/25836/

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for not being clear. I want the actual dropdown field itself, the one with the countries listed, to have a class added to it when it has not been selected (in other words when the error is triggered on "Continue" button click). So the dropdown itself should have the red border, not the error message label.